# Qu'est-ce que c'est ce qu'est-ce que c'est d'hangar à grain ?

Tags: traduction, questions, humour

Je suis actuellement en train de traduire la web-série *Le cycle des Balls*, composée de trois séries différentes, *J'ai jamais su dire non*, *La théorie des Balls* et *Le secret des Balls*. (Je traduis en amateur, je ne suis pas pro.)

Le titre est une réplique de la saison 3 qui utilise la running joke d'un des personnages qui dit "qu'est-ce que c'est?" sans forcément attendre une réponse. ([exemple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UQJSUAh-WU) tiré de la saison 1)

La réplique en question est dans l'[épisode 2 de la S3](https://youtu.be/-FvvAwwlxTQ?t=6m5s):

> — Tu saurais que le maire, il veut nous virer de la maison pour construire un qu'est-ce que c'est d'hangar à grain!
>   — **Mais qu'est-ce que c'est ce qu'est-ce que c'est d'hangar à grain** ?

Le "qu'est-ce que c'est" est utilisé dans plusieurs contextes. Dans la saison 1, on l'a surtout traduit par "what is it?" ou "what is that?" mais là, je bloque un peu. La traduction trouvée pour le moment c'est:

> What the fucking fuck, a grain shed?!

C'est plus vulgaire que la version française mais la série dans son intégralité n'a pas de problèmes avec la vulgarité (un des persos s'appellent bien Grosse Teub).

Est-ce que vous pensez que la traduction correspond?

Comment: _What's with asking about_ + object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s asking about the quality of a sentence in a language other than French, for which we are not competent to answer.

Answer (score 6):

Tout ce que je vais dire est à prendre avec des pincettes.

Voilà comment je comprends le gag : ils utilisent "qu'est-ce que c'est" comme on utiliserait les termes suivants : "un putain d'hangar à grain", "une je-sais-pas-quoi de fonction arithmétique", "cette vieille épave de bagnole" (pas dans le sens où c'est l'épave d'une voiture, mais dans le sens ou c'est une voiture qui ressemble à une épave), "ta connasse de mère", "j'ai renversé cet enfoiré de lait partout sur moi".

Je crois que justement, en anglais, tu peux dire "of a" pour ce sens familier de "de" qu'on utilise en français (et qu'on a peut-être même piqué à l'anglais, tellement la tournure semble peu justifiable ?) : "cet idiot de voisin" = "this idiot of a neighbour".

Or, la virgule en anglais transforme la phrase en : "qu'est-ce que c'est, qu'est-ce que c'est, un hangar à grain ?" alors que le sens serait, selon moi : "c'est quoi un *qu'est-ce-que-c'est d'hangar à grain* ?" qui donne donc "qu'est-ce que c'est ce *qu'est-ce-que-c'est d'hangar à grain* ?".

Moi je verrais : "What is this what-is-it-of-a-grain-shed?"

Comment: Merci :) C'est bien ça le sens du "qu'est-ce que c'est". Le "what-is-it-of" devrait aussi du coup être dans la réplique d'avant, ce qui donnerait:
[...] you'd know the mayor wants to kick us out of the house to build a what-is-it-of-a-grain-shed!
Merci du coup! Ca nous aide bien !

Comment: I'd spell it “a what-is-it of a grain shed” to better match the (fake) French grammar construction. You could also choose “a what-is-this of a grain shed”. The question then sounds a little more bizarre. “What is this what-is-this of a grain shed” adds a little more confusion, which is the whole point of the joke.

Answer (score 4):

Une phrase qui me semble bien traduire la force et le rythme de la version d'origine, sans être vulgaire, et qui marche bien dans sa répétition est *"what the hell's a"*.  C'est encore mieux à l'écriture si on remplace la deuxième phrase par un pseudo mot *"wotthehellza"*.

> what the hell's a wotthehellza grain silo?